# Xamarin Studio Finds conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly after upgrade to Azure Mobile Services 1.1.0

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I recently upgraded my Azure Mobile Services component from 1.0.3 to 1.1.0.
After the upgrade, I'm getting warnings such as

```
a.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. (MSB3247) 
b.  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. (MSB3247)
```

I think this is causing issues with my application. Any pointers on why is this happening and how to solve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have seen this warning when compiling in Visual Studio (but not Xamarin Studio). My understanding is that it is harmless and is a side effect of some issues with Xamarin's PCL support. What issues are you seeing in your application that you think might be related?

Comment: @Paul Batum :- I can see these warnings in both Visual Studio Build Output as well as Xamarin Build Warnings. I can see issues with the Azure Mobile Services Component version 1.1.0 (client logout not working as well as JSON parsing issues assuming the version itself does not have these bugs) :)

Comment: I wouldn't rule out the possibility of these being legitimate bugs. Can you post details of each issue to the GitHub repository? https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/issues

Comment: This is an issue from the Xamarin Azure Mobile Services Component. I guess I should post the issue on their GitHub repository? https://github.com/xamarin/azure-mobile-services/issues

Comment: Either place is fine. The Mobile Services component is a collaboration between Xamarin and Microsoft.

Comment: Another vote for this.